# Protobuf C# Message Translation to JAVA

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to translate a message generated using C# to JAVA. As a first step, i generated proto file and this is what i got

```
package Om.Business.Scanner;

message ScannerActivityDetail {
   optional string ActivityId = 1;
   optional string ContextId = 2;
   optional int32 ActivityStart = 3;
   optional bcl.DateTime ActivityEnd = 4;
}
```

How do i interpret bcl.DateTime in java world?

I am using protobuf-net and trying to de-serialize message generated by C# app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are using cross-platform, I would suggest handling date/times more simply as a long of some interval into an epoch (traditionally 1 jan 1970)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [`bcl.proto`](https://code.google.com/searchframe#XB9svDNAlPQ/trunk/Tools/bcl.proto), it should be pretty straightforward. Create a `Map<DateTime.TimeSpanScale, TimeUnit>` in the obvious way, then:

```
public static Date toDate(bcl.DateTime proto) {
    TimeUnit unit = SCALE_TO_UNIT_MAP.get(proto.getScale());
    if (unit == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid scale: " + proto.getScale());
    }
    long millis = unit.toMillis(proto.getValue());
    return new Date(millis);
}
```

You could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)'s `DateTime` type in exactly the same way, as it has a constructor accepting a `long` too. (You might want to think about which time zone to specify though...)