# how to deserialized data which is serialized by protobuf-net in a java program

Tags: java, c#, serialization, protocol-buffers

the data is serialized by c# protobuf-net and set to the redis,
now i want to get the data and deserialize it in a java program,everything is ok expect the datetime fields ,they can not be serialized properly.
in c# program the data is serialized from the entity as follow,and set to redis

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class TestMsg 
{
    public TestMsg();
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
}
```

in my java program,the proto flie is as follow:

```
syntax = "proto2";
option java_outer_classname = "TestMsgEntity";
message TestMsg {
    required string Message = 1;//
    required string UpdateTime = 2;// it can not be deserialized properly.if I change is to long,then i get zero .
}
```

//java code

```
byte[]  byteArrayRedis  = provider.getbyte("keyname"); //get the data from redis

ByteArrayInputStream baiContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayRedis);
try {
        TestMsgEntity.TestMsg msg = TestMsgEntity.TestMsg.parseFrom(baiContent);
        String message = msg.getMessage (); //it is ok
        String lastUpdate =msg.getLastUpdateTime();//how can i get the value? 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protobuf C# Message Translation to JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186349/protobuf-c-sharp-message-translation-to-java)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036291/how-protobuf-net-serialize-datetime & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186349/protobuf-c-sharp-message-translation-to-java

Answer (score 1):

Recently there are new "well known" contracts for describing times. Your best bet is to use "timestamp" in the java .proto, and annotate the DateTime member with the `WellKnown` data format via the `[ProtoMember]`.

To see this more simply: write a .proto (which you need to do for java anyway) that uses "timestamp", and run it through https://protogen.marcgravell.com to see what it outputs. Here's a modified version of your .proto so you can just click "Generate": https://protogen.marcgravell.com/#g38c45fbb1730d14bc4d560a13f61d2a3 - as you can see, the key bit is this:

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2,
    DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.WellKnown, IsRequired = true)]
public global::System.DateTime? UpdateTime { get; set; }
```

It is the `DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.WellKnown` that tells it to use `timestamp` notation. Similarly, this will cause a `TimeSpan` to use the well-known `duration` notation.

---

If you have preexisting data stored by protobuf-net without the well-known format, then you'll have to decode it manually via bcl.proto; I apologise that it isn't as simple as it could be, but: it needed to be *something*, and nothing "well known" existed at the time.